# Office js Hyperlink on range not working in Word Online

Tags: office-js

I have the following code in my app, trying to set the hyperlink of a range which works in Word Desktop but not in Word Online.

```
if (options.hyperlink && Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported("WordApi", 1.3))
    insertRange.hyperlink = options.hyperlink;
```

I get an error that setting the hyperlink is not allowed in Word Online but this is nowhere in the documentation to be found. Anyone have an idea how to get hyperlinks working in Word Online by office js.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in Word Online. What browser are you using? Can you provide a screen shot of the error? Also, what is the value of `options.hyperlink` and can you show how the "insertRange" object gets created?

Comment: The following also go wrong only on Word Online:                    
let insertRange = contentControl.getRange("Content");
insertRange.insertText("Hello", Word.InsertLocation.replace);
insertRange.hyperlink = "https://www.google.com";